# Using std::weak_ptr::lock() in std::tie

Tags: c++

I have a struct that contains two weak pointers, and I wish to compare this struct lexicographically using std::tie. However, I ran across a strange issue where I realized that I can't use std::weak_ptr::lock() as an argument of std::tie.
Example code:

```
struct S {
    S(std::shared_ptr<int>& f, std::shared_ptr<int>& s) {
        first = f;
        second = s;
    }
    bool operator<(const S& rhs) const {
        return std::tie(first.lock(), second.lock()) < std::tie(rhs.first.lock(), rhs.second.lock());
    }
    std::weak_ptr<int> first, second;
};
```

Doing this results in a compilation error with a code of `E0304`: `no instance of function template "std::tie" matches the argument list`.

However, if I create new `std::shared_ptr` objects and set them to the values of std::weak_ptr::lock() and then compare **them**, everything works just fine:

```
struct S {
    S(std::shared_ptr<int>& f, std::shared_ptr<int>& s) {
        first = f;
        second = s;
    }
    bool operator<(const S& rhs) const {

        // creating shared_ptrs and assigning them the value of std::weak_ptr::lock()

        std::shared_ptr<int> 
            f = first.lock(), s = second.lock(),
            rf = rhs.first.lock(), rs = rhs.second.lock();

        // compare those shared_ptrs
        return std::tie(f, s) < std::tie(rf, rs);
    }
    std::weak_ptr<int> first, second;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> 
        a(new int(10)),
        b(new int(5));

    // just two S initializations
    S foo(a, b);
    S bar(b, a);

    if (foo < bar) {
        std::cout << "Foo is less than Bar";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Otherwise";
    }

}
```

Output: `Foo is less than Bar`

Any reason as to why this may be? Thank you!

Comment: Think about it in this way. Can i lock a object not owned by me(I have weak pointer and it's reference count is not dependent on me)? What happens, if while comparing, object's reference count falls to zero?

Comment: This compiles fine with MSVC 2017 and fails with gcc 9.2 for me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This is an instance of MSVC's legacy non-standard rule allowing binding non-const reference to rvalue. MSVC also rejects it when compiling with `/permissive-`.

Comment: @aschepler Right, that explains it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::tie` is for lvalues only, creating return types such as `std::tuple<T1&, T2&>`. The `lock()` member function returns a `shared_ptr` by value, so the expression is an rvalue and cannot be used with `std::tie`.

You can use the same tuple lexicographical trick more generally by writing [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) instead:

```
return std::forward_as_tuple(first.lock(), second.lock()) < 
    std::forward_as_tuple(rhs.first.lock(), rhs.second.lock());
```

The return type of these `forward_as_tuple` calls will be `std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<int>&&, std::shared_ptr<int>&&>`. `forward_as_tuple` is a bit more dangerous than `tie` in general since it can in some uses create dangling references with no compiler warnings, but it's safe here since the `tuple` objects are temporary and will not be used after the `operator<` evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

`std::tie` takes in arguments by *reference* since it builds a tuple of references from them. Temporaries, like the `std::shared_ptr` returned by `lock()`, cannot be bound to references. Creating separate variables gives the references something to bind to.

Comment: I seemed to have missed the '&'s in the documentation of std::tie, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!